# Rails: Devise and acts_as_tenant registration process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, acts-as-tenant

I am using acts_as_tenant gem to manage a multi-tenant platform while using devise to manage users. A User in our system acts_as_tenant and belongs_to Organization. Organization acts_as_tenant and has_many Users.

We are having trouble understanding what the best way to ensure that upon sign up a User gets created, an Organization gets created, a Tenant gets created (based on the Org), and the current tenant gets saved subsequently setting the correct tenant_id on the User and Org model.

The problem is in order for a User to be valid it must have an organization and a tenant. So before validation happens we must create the org and the tenant, we are trying to do so with below code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :organization

  before_validation :create_organization

  def create_organization
    if self.organization_id.nil?
      org = Organization.new(name: self.email)
      org.uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
      self.organization_id = org.uuid
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
  self.primary_key = :uuid
  has_many :users

  before_validation :create_tenant

  def create_tenant
    puts 'making new tenant'
    t = Tenant.new(:short_name => self.name)
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  set_current_tenant_through_filter
  before_action :find_current_tenant
  def find_current_tenant
    unless current_user.nil?
      set_current_tenant(current_user.organization.tenant)
    end
  end
end
```

But the users org and tenant are not being created before validation causing validation errors 'tenant must exist', 'org must exist'.

Any help on best practices here?

Comment: What is the `t = Tenant.new..` class you are initializing on `create_tenant`?

Comment: That is the new tenant that we need to set as current tenant and ensure the new user and new organization gets associated with as well.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm not sure your Tenant model is necessary, so I'd love to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your business logic but in order to do
`acts_as_tenant(:tenant)` your model has to have a relation defined to `tenant`, which you don't seem to have. 
I think what you want to do (common use case) is:

```
class User < ActionController::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  acts_as_tenant(:organization)
end

class Organization < ActionController::Base
  self.primary_key = :uuid
  has_many :users
  # and nothing else
end
```

You don't set the current tenant on the model. That is not correct. You do that on the Application Controller, by doing `set_current_tenant(current_user.organization)` and nothing else

UPDATE: You mentionew a Tenant class now.

So now your organization class should define that relation

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
  self.primary_key = :uuid
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :tenant

  before_validation :create_tenant

  def create_tenant
    puts 'making new tenant'
    self.tenant ||= Tenant.create!(:short_name => self.name)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is helping.. although our Organizations are tenanted too. Also, what is the correct way to associate my user to a new organization because I can't save the user or the organization until my tenant is set

Comment: What do you mean organizations are tenanted too? To what model? There is always one model that does not have the `acts_as_tenant` because it IS the tenant, in your case sounds like `organization` is that model

Comment: Tenant is that model in our case

Comment: Okay so you are missing code on your post. Please include the `Tenant` model and the relation that the class `user` or `organization` has with that class.

Comment: the User and Organization model are simply acts_as_tenant(:tenant) the tenant model is just: class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base


  acts_as_paranoid

  include TenantHelper


  has_many :system_properties


  class << self

    def find!(tenant_id)
      find(tenant_id).as_current_tenant!
    end

  end

end

Comment: But does `user` or `organization` `belong_to :tenant` ? Else it won't work!

Comment: No, that's not true because the belongs_to gets set within the acts_as_tenant gem..